# Commerce_paypal doctrine/annotations error

Tags: 8, commerce

My site's core and modules are completely up to date including commerce.
I'm trying to install **commerce_paypal** via `composer require drupal/commerce_paypal`.
I've tried `--with-dependencies` and also (~)versions and (^)versions.
Here is the error...

[image]

I have also tried a similar set of commands which worked to get me to core 8.7.7. following a similar `doctrine/annotations` error, see below...

```
rm composer.lock
rm vendor -rf
composer clear-cache
composer require --dev drupal/commerce_paypal
composer update
```

Then I ran: composer why drupal/commerce_paypal and got...

[image]

I'm just wondering what I could try next, please?

Comment: Try with `composer require 'drupal/commerce_paypal:^1.0`

Comment: `--dev` installs packages listed in require-dev, which is probably not what you want. You want it in the normal require section. And if you want a dev version that would be `composer require drupal/commerce_paypal:1.x-dev`.

Comment: @berramou – There's a typo in your command, you forgot to add a closing single quote at the end, no?

Comment: Hi. I tried the first suggestion with both single quotes and the same error occurred. I then tried that series of commands just without the '--dev' bit but while trying to update dependencies it just said 'killed'?

Comment: @leymannx  yes i forget the single quote at the end sorry

Comment: Try to update `doctrine/annotations` first like `composer update doctrine/annotations --with-dependencies` and then `composer require 'drupal/commerce_paypal:^1.0'`

Comment: Don't I need to downgrade from 1.7 to 1.2? I tried the doctrine update and got 50 lines saying: 
Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove paragonie/random_compat v9.99.99
    - Conclusion: don't install paragonie/random_compat v9.99.99
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[1.0.10, v9.99.99]

Comment: This is not a Commerce problem. I assume the same error will show up whichever module you try to require, because there is an error in either your composer.json or your vendor folder (which you can try blasting away and then rerunning composer)

Comment: Hi, yes the same error occurred installing commerce_worldpay. I tried removing the composer.lock and vendor folder but got the same error after rerunning composer. Is there anything else I could try, please?

Comment: I updated drupal/drupal to drupal/core and 8.8.1. Ran `composer require drupal/commerce_paypal --prefer-dist`. 
but `'[InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find a version of package drupal/commerce_paypal matching your minimum-stability (stable). Require it with an explicit version constraint allowing its desired stability.` I add `"minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,` to composer.json but `Using version ^1.0@beta for drupal/commerce_paypal ./composer.json has been updated Loading composer repositories with package information.....
Killed`
What else could I try?